# Facebook Page Like From android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I want to integrate a facebook like button. Basically i want to like a page from my android Application. I have read many articles but found that in new SDK, no such provision is provided, or if provided then it is by using the web view only. I don't want to use web View as it is not preserving the state to check whether i am logged in. Please help.

Comment: I think there's no other way to integrate `like` button in android as your application could not maintain the state of `facebook login`. So you have to do it via `Web view` which might redirect the user to like specified page through URL

Comment: Dear this i know very well but i am looking for a way that we can implement it without using Webview

Comment: Facebook has not provided any provision for that.